# Position div in navbar vertically center and to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of links in a navbar. Most of the links are positioned to the left. I want to position some of the links to the right (`right-side-login-cart`). The part that is giving me trouble is that I can get the links to the right, but then cannot get the links to vertically align.

I've tried a bunch of different things to get it to work. For instance, I have `float:right;`, used `transform` to translate Y, and tried to used vertical align.

Some different attempts:

**HTML**

```
<div class="links-at-top">
    <div class="links-div">
        <a href="/">
          <img src="example.com/img">
        </a>
        <a href="/link-1">Link1</a>
        <a href="/link-2">Link2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <div class="positioning">
            <a id="right-link-1">RightLink1</a>
            <a id="right-link-2">RightLink2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Attempt 1:**

CSS:

```
.right-side {
    padding-right: 50px;
    display: inline-block;  
}
.positioning {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);        
}
```

**Attempt 2:**

CSS:

```
.right-side {
    padding-right: 50px;
    display: inline-block;  
}
.positioning {
    vertical-align: middle;     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your .right-side div into the same div as your other links so that they'll be on the same line. Then you can just float right.

```css
.links-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="links-at-top">
    <div class="links-div">
    
        <div>
            <a href="/link-1">Link1</a>
            <a href="/link-2">Link2</a>
        </div>

        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" alt="" />

        <div>
            <a id="right-link-1">RightLink1</a>
            <a id="right-link-2">RightLink2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They are floating up into the top right corner of the div (not vertically aligned in the middle)

Comment: Added a border and padding for clarity. Looks vertically centered.

Comment: If you add padding then it will surround the text, so that makes sense. In this instance there is an image which is increasing the overall height of the div, but not padding all of the text. The text is in the center until float is applied, at which point it no longer vertically centers.

Comment: You should have included that image in your post then! Updated with flexbox :)

Comment: Adjusting the question. Is there a way without flex-box? Doesn't that limit the number of browsers it will operate on?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using flex-box

```css
.links-at-top{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="links-at-top">
    <div class="links-div">
        <a href="/link-1">Link1</a>
        <a href="/link-2">Link2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
        <div class="positioning">
            <a id="right-link-1">RightLink1</a>
            <a id="right-link-2">RightLink2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make .links-div and .right-side both display:inline-block, and float the right-side to right.

```
<div class="links-at-top">
<div class="links-div"> 
    <a href="/link-1">Link1</a>
    <a href="/link-2">Link2</a>
</div>
<div class="right-side">
    <ul class="positioning">
       <li> <a id="right-link-1">RightLink1</a></li>
       <li> <a id="right-link-2">RightLink2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.right-side {   
     display: inline-block;  
     float:right;  
 }

.links-div{
  display:inline-block;
 }
```